# Table not getting created when persisting values in file system when using H2 database

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

Am setting up a basic CRUD app in Spring and facing issue in automatic creation of table post app start **when persisting values in file system** instead of in-memory.

Below is my Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PropertyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String ownerName;
    private String price;
    private String address;
    private String ownerEmail;

}
```

Below is the H2 config in app.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:D:/coderunner/pmsdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

After the Spring application is started and I check the H2 console, I could see the table Property_Entity isn't present and when triggering saving of entity,  it throws below error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Sequence "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" not found; SQL statement:
call next value for hibernate_sequence [90036-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:632) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
```

However after adding below property, the table creation happens automatically on application start.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

My concern is when I use H2's in-memory storage for persisting values, I do not need to add the above ddl property and the table creation happens automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why it happens is because h2 in-memory is considered embedded and will use default ddl=create-drop while h2 with file storage will use default ddl=none
(see org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider -> getDefaultDdlAuto())

```
class HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider implements SchemaManagementProvider {

private final Iterable<SchemaManagementProvider> providers;

HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider(Iterable<SchemaManagementProvider> providers) {
    this.providers = providers;
}

String getDefaultDdlAuto(DataSource dataSource) {
    if (!EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(dataSource)) {
        return "none";
    }
    SchemaManagement schemaManagement = getSchemaManagement(dataSource);
    if (SchemaManagement.MANAGED.equals(schemaManagement)) {
        return "none";
    }
    return "create-drop";
}
```

The reason why the in-memory is considered embeded you can see in the following predicate: `(url) -> url.contains(":h2:mem")`

```
public enum EmbeddedDatabaseConnection {

/**
 * No Connection.
 */
NONE(null, null, null, (url) -> false),

/**
 * H2 Database Connection.
 */
H2(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2, DatabaseDriver.H2.getDriverClassName(),
        "jdbc:h2:mem:%s;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE", (url) -> url.contains(":h2:mem")),
```